# Can't build docker image after upgrade

Tags: docker, poppler

After a recent upgrade (including Ubuntu proposed repo)
this command started failing:

```
docker -D build .
```

It failed at random lines in my `Dockerfile` on things like setting an environment variable:

```
failed to export image: failed to set parent
sha256:1209386865e4a395004592f49943a2ceee54f9b77800062b1fcd48b7ce58b592: 
unknown parent image ID 
sha256:1209386865e4a395004592f49943a2ceee54f9b77800062b1fcd48b7ce58b592

failed to get digest
sha256:2630e04441b4f54a6f2df481ecac83071fa89078c192de90be1ffb9069806964: 
open 
/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/2630e04441b4f54a6f2df481ecac83071fa89078c192de90be1ffb9069806964:
no such file or directory
```

Normally in severe cases of possible corruption I do the below but this time it didn't help:

```
service docker stop
/var/lib/docker/
service docker stop
```

Answer (score 1):

After days of struggling, I finally laid my hands on it and figured out that the `poppler` packages was somehow responsible, I removed them:

```
libpoppler58:amd64 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.4
poppler-utils:amd64 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.4
libpoppler-glib8:amd64 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.4
libpoppler-qt4-4:amd64 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.4
libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.4
```

restarted docker and then it worked \o/

**Update:**

I tried version `0.41.0-0ubuntu1.4` (security repo) today but that also broke it and then reverting back to `0.41.0-0ubuntu1` fixed it again.

**Update:**

I tried version `0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5` of `poppler-utils:i386` and `libpoppler58:i386` (security repo) today but that also broke it and then reverting back to `0.41.0-0ubuntu1` but now it is still broken :'( . **In the end I uninstalled docker-ce and re-installed docker.io and that worked \o/.** (I even tried the snap version of docker but unfortunately I could not get it to work, with all of it's quirks)

Comment: see my other answer that finally laid this to rest..

Answer (score 0):

*I still had these issues on and off until now when in an answer to my prayers Anthony Farquharson sugested I try the following before trying a complete re-install:*

```
apt remove docker-ce 
apt purge docker-ce 
apt purge docker.io 
# delete all docker configs in /etc 
# doublecheck apt repo for docker
apt install docker-ce
```